# which iOS versions are supported by Flutter web

Tags: flutter, service-worker

I made a Flutter web application which runs fine on recent iOS/Android/desktops.
However, it doesn't run on older iPads (running iOS 9.3.5 or 10.3.3), not on Safari and not on Chrome.  This triggers a number of questions

- Does there exist a list of iOS/browser versions that are supported by Flutter web?
- I noticed that the generated index.html uses serviceWorkers.  Is it possible that this  determines whether flutter web is supported or not (I think that serviceWorkers are only supported from iOS 11.3 onwards).
- Is it possible to start the flutter app without using service workers?

Comment: 1. [Here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/supported-platforms) you can find all supported versions and platforms.
2.  Unfortunately, too little information about it.
3. Try to use `--pwa-strategy=none`, or you may find answer [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/initialization#loading-the-entrypoint). If you don't use `service worker` prop it won’t be used.

Comment: @kizer256 Thank you for your input! If you convert your comment to an aswer, then I can award you the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

1. [Here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/supported-platforms) you can find all supported versions and platforms.
2. Unfortunately, too little information about it.
3. Try to use `--pwa-strategy=none`, or you may find answer [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/initialization#loading-the-entrypoint). If you don't use `service worker` prop it won’t be used.

Best regards ✋